# It's possible to open getLoginUrl inside facebook page iframe?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried to open it inside facebook iframe but it show a pic of facebook and when i click on this pic it redirect to a new window, i rly need to open it inside iframe.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not possible according to this:

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19838

This is intentional behaviour as the Auth dialog cannot be loaded in anything
other than Page or Popup mode. This is to protect the user experience - the
Permissions dialog needs to retain special security.